# StackInTheFlow - An IntelliJ plugin to query Stack Overflow

Tags: app, stackoverflow, dev-tool

## StackInTheFlow [image]

An IntelliJ plugin to query Stack Overflow.

#### Search Stack Overflow Without Leaving the IDE

StackInTheFlow integrates seamlessly with Intellij to allow you to find the solutions to the development problems you face without ever leaving the *flow* of your development environment.

[image: Search]

#### Automatically Generate Queries from your Code

Take your automation one step further by having StackInTheFlow generate queries for you. Either generate a query from an editor tab or select a block of code, then right-click and select Auto Query!

[image: Auto]

#### Receive Smart Recommendations to Accelerate your Workflow

If enabled, StackInTheFlow with make suggestions of Stack Overflow articles when it thinks they will help you out with your current task, ensuring relevant information is always at your fingertips. Never manually search for the meaning behind a cryptic error message again!

[image: Error]

#### Sort & Filter

Refine your searches by sorting by different metrics and filtering by specific tags. If you never want to leave the comfort of your keyboard, you can even press `<TAB>` to add the previous word as a tag.

[image: Filter]

### Download

The plugin can be downloaded via the [StackInTheFlow](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9653-stackintheflow) Intellij plugin page or the in-IDE plugin browser.

### Requirements

StackInTheFlow is compatible with Intellij 2016.2 and later.

### Source

The source of StackInTheFlow is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/vcu-swim-lab/stack-intheflow).

### License

MIT

### Contact

VCU Software Improvement Lab
vcuswim@gmail.com